# On prem to on prem migration?

Tags: opshub

Your web site states the migration utility supports migration between on prem servers. However when I attempt to set the endpoint to an on prem collection I get the error "You can only select Visual Studio Teams Service's team project collection." Is this feature available? If so how do I configure a basic migration between two on-prem collections then?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in commercial version of migration utility. Please contact sales@opshub.com for upgrading utility.
Free version of utility will provide TFS on prem to VSTS migration.